# How to connect 3 wifi routers in a home network

Tags: home-networking

My ISP brings in a cat5e cable into the house from a switch on my roof. It's a line of sight microwave system with the modem on the dish.

I have two Rasberry Pi 3b VPN routers, an older Cisco WRT54GL wifi router running DD-WRT and an unmanaged Netgear (CG105?) 5 port gigabit switch.

From what I've read, I think that I can use all three at the same time if, each has a separate IP address and two of them operate in bridged mode and their gateway is configured properly.

I'm confused how this would actually be done assuming this is the correct idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have the right general idea.

Your ISP brings an IP based internet connection into your house. You will usually only have one public IP address available, which makes a (NAT)router necessary. This allows you to share that single public address with many private devices (e.g. Phone, PC, Raspberry Pi, etc.) via **N**etwork **A**ddress **T**ranslation (NAT).

Many consumer WiFi access points will offer, in addition to their WiFi capability, this NAT service. You actually only need this once. So if you already have a designated device for NAT/router duty, all other devices should have this service disabled. This includes Firewall/DHCP/NAT service. Access points often call this mode AP-Mode, or bridge mode. There is technically a differences between the two, but can be ignored here. AP-mode is preferable if available.

For your dd-wrt wifi router there is a couple of settings to adjust to disables it routing service as can be seen [here](https://x3mtek.com/how-to-convert-a-dd-wrt-router-into-an-access-point/). Generally you want to

- use its LAN ports
- set static IP within the IP range of your main router (e.g. 192.168.1.200)
- most importantly, disable DHCP server

Your IP network could look like this:

```
 ISP/Internet 
      |
      |
 NAT/Router -------- Switch --- Raspery Pi
 192.168.1.1           |        192.168.1.52
                       |
                       |------- Access Point1 - -(wifi) - - Phone1
                       |        192.168.1.200               192.168.1.53
                       |
                        ------- Access Point2 - -(wifi) - - Phone2
                                192.168.1.201               192.168.1.54
```

Comment: Great answer. I'll have to come back to this more later today when wife allows :)

Comment: Thank you, and wish you success with your setup.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar and your explanation cleared up the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is somewhat, "it depends on what you want to do."

I would guess one of the more generally useful things is to use them to increase the range of your WiFi signal by creating a WiFi mesh network.  Most routers implement some version of the WDS (WiFi Distribution System).  In this system, you choose one router as your "base station" - that would be the one physically connected to your ISP's hardware, and providing the NAT function between your network and the internet.  Then you'd configure the others as WiFi Access Points (WAP), define the WAP MAC address(s) in the right place on the base station, and vice versa, and configure the SSID/Authentication/Password the same everywhere.  Then, your wifi devices will be able to connect to the station that has the strongest signal but all appear to be on the same WiFi network.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. My first object was just to get 3 wifi AP's working on a single switch. Turns out this most basic setup is easier than I thought. I should also try something more akin to your suggestion next.